# Let V be a normed vector space. Show that its norm is induced by a scalar product if and only if it satisfies the parallelogramm inequality.

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

I managed to prove left to right, but I found it hard to get the other direction even if I have the [polarization identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity).

I've found [Fréchet - Von Neumann - Jordan theorem](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m113w10/public_html/jordan-vneumann-thm.pdf) that proves exactly what I want, but it seems highly unlikely that the author would require such a proof in the first chapter of his analysis manual.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Polarisation identity?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity
It gives you an expression for a unique representation of a scalar product given the norm.

Comment: Okay, never knew it (the P.I.) had such a high-falutin' name. I somehow overlooked the first sentence of your question, and meant that to be a hint. Yes, you use the polarisation identity to construct an inner product when the parallelogram law holds. It's not so difficult to prove, and I'm pretty sure that's what was expected. To the best of my knowledge, there is nothing simpler than that to prove it.

Comment: This must be a duplicate.

Comment: I searched and didn't find any similar questions. Could you provide a link, please?

Comment: @DanielFischer, can you form your comment as an answer please, so that I could accept it?
Apparently, I understood it right and I'll have to prove the existence of the scalar product point by point using the polarization identity.

Answer (score 1):

There is the following proof in Russian book *Kolmogorov, Fomin. Elements of theory of functions and functional analysis.* that seems simpler than that you linked (although it might be more hard to make by thinking).

Let $f,g\in V$ and $\|f+g\|^2+\|f-g\|^2=2(\|f\|^2+\|g\|^2).$

Let $\langle f,g\rangle=\frac{1}{4}\left ( \|f+g\|^2-\|f-g\|^2\right)$ and show that it satisfies the properties of inner product.

It is obvious that $\langle f,g\rangle = \langle g,f\rangle$.

$\langle f,f\rangle=\frac{1}{4}(\|2f\|^2-\|f-f\|^2)=\|f\|^2$

Now, let $\Phi(f,g,h)=4(\langle f+g,h\rangle -\langle f,h\rangle-\langle g,h\rangle)$, that is $$\Phi(f,g,h)=\|f+g+h\|^2-\|f+g-h\|^2-\|f+h\|^2+\|f-h\|^2-\|g+h\|^2+\|g-h\|^2$$

Due to polarisation identity $$\|f+g\pm h\|^2=2\|f \pm h\|^2+2\|g\|^2-\|f \pm h-g\|^2$$.

Substituting the last result into $\Phi$, we get $$\Phi(f,g,h)=-\|f+h-g\|^2+\|f-h-g\|^2+\|f+h\|^2-\|f-h\|^2-\|g+h\|^2+\|g-h\|^2$$

Now we take half sum of two expressions for $\Phi$: $$\Phi(f,g,h)=\frac{1}{2}(\|g+h+f\|+\|g+h-f\|^2)-\frac{1}{2}(\|g-h+f\|^2+\|g-h-f\|^2)-\|g+h\|^2+\|g-h\|^2$$

Due to the identity the first term equals $\|g+h\|^2+\|f\|^2$ and the second one equals $-\|g-h\|^2-\|f\|^2$.

Thus, $\Phi(f,h,g) \equiv 0$ and we proved linearity in the first argument.

The last property is left to prove.

Let $f,g$ be fixed. Let us define a function $\varphi(c)=c\langle f,g\rangle - c\langle f,g\rangle$.

It's obvious that $\varphi(0)=\frac{1}{4}(\|g\|^2-\|g\|^2)=0$ and $\varphi(-1)=0$, because $\langle -f,g\rangle = -\langle f,g\rangle$

For any integer $n$: $$\langle nf, g\rangle = \langle \text{sign } n(f + \dots f) = \text{sign }n ( \langle f,g \rangle + \dots \langle f,g \rangle )=|n|\text{sign } n \langle f,g\rangle = n\langle f,g\rangle$$

So $\varphi(n)=0$.

For integer $p,q,q \ne 0$:

$$\langle \frac{p}{q} f, g \rangle = p \langle \frac{1}{q}f, g \rangle=\frac{p}{q}q\rangle \frac{1}{q} f, g \rangle = \frac{p}{q} \langle f, g\rangle g$$

Hence $\varphi(c)=0 \, \forall c \in \mathbb Q$ but $\varphi$ is continuous, so $\varphi(c)=0$ and all properties of inner product are satisfied.

Comment: Thank you, @ТимофейЛомоносов, but it feels like exactly the same approach as described in my link with the exception that the polarization identity used is for the specific case of real valued functions. Since it is not explicitly mentioned in the problem, my proof should work for the more general case of complex valued functions too.

Comment: Although it is not proven in the book I mentioned there is a similar expression in case of unitary or hilbert space: $$\langle f,g \rangle = \frac{1}{4}(\|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2)+\frac{i}{4}(\|x+iy\|^2-\|x-iy\|^2)$$ The proof can be construced as an analogue.

Comment: Yes, and this is exactly the formula used in my link. My question was: is there a simpler way (maybe, using some other facts, lemmas or theorems) that might be used to prove it. Since it is just a problem from a manual, it shouldn't be so long/hard to solve.

Comment: As far as I know, there aren't simpler proofs but that doesn't mean that they don't exist. The one I quoted seemed less dificult than one in the link to me.